# AWS: Give only a specific ec2 instance access to a Beanstalk app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Elastic Beanstalk app, and I want only instances with a specific securitygroup to be able to connect to it. I don`t mean the instances which are managed by the load balancer: I mean other instances started in EC2.

So I started an EC2 instance, and added the securitygroup "my-group". After that, I edited the securitygroup of my load balancer, to not allow all traffic on port 80, only from Custom-IP, and added the securitygroup "my-group" as Custom-IP.

But the instance is not able to connect to the load balancer. It timeouts.

What am I doing wrong? How is it possible to give only instances I want to have access the access to my beanstalk app?